# ArchLinux Availability of lotus notes dependencies in multilib repository

Tags: dependencies, lotus-notes, 32bit-64bit, archlinux

I'm a `Debian` (Stretch 64bit) user for several years and am currently in the process of testing `Archlinux` (64bit). I have sucessfully installed `Juniper Network Connect` (VPN) in my `Archlinux` distribution, using the necessary dependencies available in the `multilib` repository, and have successfully installed `Lotus Notes 9.0.1` in a 32bit chroot environment. However, I would like to understand why it seems not possible to install `Lotus Notes` in the 64bit environment (at least this is what I've read), only relying on `multilib`. I mean that most of the `Lotus Notes` dependencies seem not to be available in the `multilib` directory.

Some dependencies are available in the `multilib` repo:

```
[me@arch ~]$ pacman -Ss libxrender | grep multilib
multilib/lib32-libxrender 0.9.9-1 [installed]
```

...whereas some others (actually most of the requested ones) are not:

```
[me@arch ~]$ pacman -Ss bonobo
extra/libbonobo 2.32.1-4
    A set of language and system independant CORBA interfaces for creating reusable components
extra/libbonoboui 2.24.5-3
    User Interface library for Bonobo
extra/python2-bonobo 2.28.1-9
    Python bindings for interacting with Bonobo
```

Another question: even in my 32bit chroot, some dependencies were not available in the `official` repos and I had to get them from `AUR`:

```
[me@arch /]$ pacman -Ss libgnomeprint
[me@arch /]$ yaourt -Ss libgnomeprint
aur/libgnomeprint 2.18.8-8 [installed] (152) (0.32)
    Printing routines for GNOME
aur/libgnomeprintui 2.18.6-5 [installed] (110) (0.00)
    User interface library for printing with GNOME
```

That said, I have been able to install all of my required applications in Arch, but I have the feeling it's a bit dirty (multi-arch environment + 32 bit chroot + AUR) and ideally, I would be more comfortable having everything installed as multi-arch as I used to have in my Debian (no need to maintain a 32bit chroot or have non-official libs).

Any feedback would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question belongs on either SuperUser or ServerFault. I'm not sure which one is more appropriate, but it's definitely not StackOverflow question since it's not a software development question.

Answer (score 0):

OK thank you for your comment @Richard. I've asked the question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/776998/archlinux-availability-of-lotus-notes-dependencies-in-multilib-repository